# Flutter, How to get all the image file name from images folder?

Tags: flutter

I want to load all the image **file names** in images/pets/ to `List<String> animals`. How can I do that?

Comment: That's more of a Dart question.

Comment: Do you want to load from disk or the local assets folder shipped with the application?

Comment: Yes @FilledStacks

Comment: @YaungWal Which one is it? You want to load it from Disk(The phone's disk space) or from the assets folder that the application ships with?

Comment: I want to load from the local assets folder shipped with the application. @FilledStacks

Comment: @YaungWal ok cool. I added my answer below, that'll work for your purpose.

Answer (score 7):

[path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) you can get the directory the temp and appDir directory

```
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String imagesDirectory = directory + "/images/pets/";
```

After you can use the [listSync](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/Directory/listSync.html) method to find files of this Directory

```
final myDir = new Directory(imagesDirectory);
List<FileSystemEntity> _images;
_images = myDir.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: false);
```

I hope that I have helped in some way

Comment: I want to list all images of /assets/images/wallpapers/ directory and store them in a List type variable to use further, how can i do?

Answer (score 5):

Flutter generates a file called AssetManifest.json which you can read up through the default bundle the same way you would read a normal text file from the assets.

```
var manifestContent = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');
```

Read and parse this file and then create a list from all the properties you need with their paths. Just double check to make sure you have the correct path, this can change in the future. It seems to me like a placeholder.

**Pseudo-code for reading AssetManifest.json**

```
var manifestContent = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');
var manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);

var imagePetPaths = manifestMap.keys.where((key) => key.contains('images/pets/'));

// You can either use the keys and fetch the value from the map, 
or just use the key value since it's the same as the one in the pubspec.yaml
```

Comment: Hi! @FilledStacks  I dont't know how to do the way with AssetManifest.json. Can you show me some example  or show helpful links?

Comment: Hi @YaungWal I don't have any examples or helpful links. Just read the json, decode it into a map using json.decode from the dart:convert package and then get all the keys that contains 'images/pets'. I'll add some pseudo-code in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you @FilledStacks I will try it.

Comment: @FilledStacks the 'AssetManifest.json' file which you mentioned about will be autogenerated or should I have to create it manually? Also will you pls show the structue like what is contains and I want a short description with my every image

Comment: @Sachin You can check in your apk after it's built or in the build folder. it should be there in the flutter assets directore.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from AdsHan's Answer

```
final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final imagesDirectory = Directory(dir.path + "/images/pets/");

List<String> images = [];
final _imagesFile = imagesDirectory.listSync(followLinks: false, recursive: true);
_imagesFile.forEach((img) {
       String imgString = img.toString().substring(
       img.toString().lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
       img.toString().length);
       images.add(imgString); 
});
```